# Customization of the angular material components

Tags: angular, angular-material

As per my requirement I have to add property for customization of the angular material components.

How to override the default behavior and adding new property, function and template on the angular material components globally?

Answer (score 0):

i just edit in css file
ex for mat-toolbar

```css
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
    background: #673ab7;
    color: #fff;
}
```